# QTCreator extern not working on specific PC

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

Hi I am currently working on a tournament creator program using QT Creator. I have been working on it at work during my lunch breaks and it has ran fine, but I have brought it home to get it finished for this weekend and it doesnt work.

The error which I am getting is

```
F:\Documents\Coding\TournamentOrganiser\startscreen.cpp:-1: error: multiple
definition of `StartScreen::StartScreen(QWidget*)'
```

I have literally only taken the folder placed it on a USB, copied it onto my desktop and ran it and this occurs, when it worked fine at home.

I assume that it is some kind of QT Creator configuration setting but just in case these are the files which are involved in the issue. If anyone can help me out with this it would be much appreciated as I need this working on my desktop for Saturday when I will need to use the app.

```
template <typename T> using shp = std::shared_ptr<T>;
```

globals.h

```
#ifndef GLOBALS_H
#define GLOBALS_H

#include "startscreen.h"
#include "tournamentcreator.h"
#include "player.h"
#include <memory>
#include "util.h"
#include "matchups.h"

namespace globals{
  extern shp<StartScreen> g_StartScreen;
  extern shp<TournamentCreator> g_TournamentCreator;
  extern shp<std::vector<Player>> g_PlayerData;
  extern shp<MatchUps> g_MatchUps;
}

#endif // GLOBALS_H
```

main.cpp

```
#include "startscreen.h"
#include "tournamentcreator.h"
#include "matchups.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include "util.h"

namespace globals{
  shp<StartScreen> g_StartScreen;
  shp<TournamentCreator> g_TournamentCreator;
  shp<std::vector<Player>> g_PlayerData;
  shp<MatchUps> g_MatchUps;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication a(argc, argv);
  globals::g_StartScreen = std::make_shared<StartScreen>();
  globals::g_TournamentCreator = std::make_shared<TournamentCreator>();
  globals::g_PlayerData = std::make_shared<std::vector<Player>>();
  globals::g_MatchUps = std::make_shared<MatchUps>();

  globals::g_StartScreen->show();

  return a.exec();
}
```

startscreen.h

```
#ifndef STARTSCREEN_H
#define STARTSCREEN_H

#include <QWidget>

namespace Ui {
class StartScreen;
}

class StartScreen : public QWidget
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  explicit StartScreen(QWidget *parent = 0);
  ~StartScreen();
private slots:
  void on_newEventButton_clicked();

private:
  Ui::StartScreen *ui;
};

#endif // STARTSCREEN_H
```

startscreen.cpp

```
#include "startscreen.h"
#include "ui_startscreen.h"
#include "globals.h"

StartScreen::StartScreen(QWidget *parent) :
  QWidget(parent),
  ui(new Ui::StartScreen)
{
  ui->setupUi(this);
}

StartScreen::~StartScreen()
{
  delete ui;
}

void StartScreen::on_newEventButton_clicked(){
  this->hide();
  globals::g_TournamentCreator->show();
}
```

Comment: Note that Qt Creator is irrelevant. It's just an IDE. What fails is the compilation, and the error is reported by the compiler.

Comment: Please edit the question to add the project file as well.